# JMVC jQuery.Model - cannot override a standard REST URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, model, javascriptmvc

I am using Javascript MVC models separately from JMVC (just as a jquery plugin).

Everything works fine, instead of overriding REST URLs. Look:

I am trying to override URL to retrieve data from server.
But it still tries to load data from URL "/Tags.json" instead of "/t.json".

```
$.Model.extend("Tag",
{
    findAll: "/t.json" //overriding URL for findAll (just like in the manual)
});

$(function(){
    Tag.findAll({}); //loads '/Tags.json' instead of 't.json'
})
```

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.Model("Tag",{
  findAll : "/t.json"
},{})
```

You need to call `$.Model` not `$.Model.extend`

[`.findAll` docs](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/docs/jQuery.Model.html#&who=jQuery.Model.static.findAll)

Comment: it does not matter. only second parameter (empty `{}`) really matters as i have found out